# What does <a:theme> mean in OpenXML?

Tags: openxml-sdk, openxml, spreadsheetml

I'm try to understand OpenXML spreadsheet inner file content.
IN some file I found this string . Other tags has same prefix.
Also tags may have prefixes p: w: etc.

Can you help me undestend the meaning of these prefixes in tags?

Answer (score 3):

You can search for each tag and the full specification of Open XML at [DII](http://www.documentinteropinitiative.org/implnotes/ECMA-376/P1-TOC.aspx) or download the PDF from the [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51463) site to read offline. All of these tags have a specific meaning in the construction of one or more formats for Word/Excel/PowerPoint 2007/2010 documents, spreadsheets and presentations.

The one that you mentioned above, `<a:theme>` is the parent tag for the construction of different templated looks/feel documents, such as their fonts, font sizes, color schemas, etc. See [here](http://www.documentinteropinitiative.org/implnotes/ECMA-376/P1-14.2.7.aspx#_Toc147891882) for a description.

If you're looking to get a little more familiar with the standard, there is a great eBook that can be downloaded and read: [Open XML Markup Explained](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6f264d0b-23e8-43fe-9f82-9ab627e5eaa3&displaylang=en).

Comment: +1 for other sources I didn't know about.  They are also defined in the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool under the Open XML SDK Documentation tab.

Comment: +1 for great links.  I hadn't come across the Open XML Markup Explained book in my searches.

Comment: Not sure if it's wiki'ed elsewhere - but I've found that there isn't a single comprehensive source out there for Open XML.